# data truncated for column 3 by using enum

Tags: javascript

I would to edit a code source from English to french. In the database a table has a colum with data `enum('Male','Female')` that I wish to change into `enum('Homme','Femme')`. Impossible and I receive a message like data truncated for colum 3.

I find the same information in some java file. When I change it only without change the database I receive the same errors.

What can I do?

---

this a part of code in lib.js

```
    EmployeeAdapter.method('getFormFields', function() {

var newFields = [];
var tempField, title;
var fields = [
    [ "id", {"label":"ID","type":"hidden","validation":""}],
    [ "employee_id", {"label":"Employee Number","type":"text","validation":""}],
    [ "first_name", {"label":"First Name","type":"text","validation":""}],
    [ "middle_name", {"label":"Middle Name","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "last_name", {"label":"Last Name","type":"text","validation":""}],
    [ "nationality", {"label":"Nationality","type":"select2","remote-source":["Nationality","id","name"]}],
    [ "birthday", {"label":"Date of Birth","type":"date","validation":""}],
    [ "gender", {"label":"Gender","type":"select","source":[["Male","Male"],["Female","Female"]]}],
    [ "marital_status", {"label":"Marital Status","type":"select","source":[["Married","Married"],["Single","Single"],["Divorced","Divorced"],["Widowed","Widowed"],["Other","Other"]]}],
    [ "ethnicity", {"label":"Ethnicity","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"remote-source":["Ethnicity","id","name"]}],
    [ "immigration_status", {"label":"Immigration Status","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"remote-source":["ImmigrationStatus","id","name"]}],
    [ "ssn_num", {"label":"SSN/NRIC","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "nic_num", {"label":"NIC","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "other_id", {"label":"Other ID","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "driving_license", {"label":"Driving License No","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "employment_status", {"label":"Employment Status","type":"select2","remote-source":["EmploymentStatus","id","name"]}],
    [ "job_title", {"label":"Job Title","type":"select2","remote-source":["JobTitle","id","name"]}],
    [ "pay_grade", {"label":"Pay Grade","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"remote-source":["PayGrade","id","name"]}],
    [ "work_station_id", {"label":"Work Station Id","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "address1", {"label":"Address Line 1","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "address2", {"label":"Address Line 2","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "city", {"label":"City","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "country", {"label":"Country","type":"select2","remote-source":["Country","code","name"]}],
    [ "province", {"label":"State","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"remote-source":["Province","id","name"]}],
    [ "postal_code", {"label":"Postal/Zip Code","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "home_phone", {"label":"Home Phone","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "mobile_phone", {"label":"Mobile Phone","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "work_phone", {"label":"Work Phone","type":"text","validation":"none"}],
    [ "work_email", {"label":"Work Email","type":"text","validation":"emailOrEmpty"}],
    [ "private_email", {"label":"Private Email","type":"text","validation":"emailOrEmpty"}],
    [ "joined_date", {"label":"Joined Date","type":"date","validation":""}],
    [ "confirmation_date", {"label":"Confirmation Date","type":"date","validation":"none"}],
    [ "termination_date", {"label":"Termination Date","type":"date","validation":"none"}],
    [ "department", {"label":"Department","type":"select2","remote-source":["CompanyStructure","id","title"]}],
    [ "supervisor", {"label":"Direct Supervisor","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"remote-source":["Employee","id","first_name+last_name"]}],
    [ "indirect_supervisors", {"label":"Indirect Supervisors","type":"select2multi","allow-null":true,"remote-source":["Employee","id","first_name+last_name"]}],
    [ "approver1", {"label":"First Level Approver","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"null-label":"None","remote-source":["Employee","id","first_name+last_name"]}],
    [ "approver2", {"label":"Second Level Approver","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"null-label":"None","remote-source":["Employee","id","first_name+last_name"]}],
    [ "approver3", {"label":"Third Level Approver","type":"select2","allow-null":true,"null-label":"None","remote-source":["Employee","id","first_name+last_name"]}],
    [ "notes", {"label":"Notes","type":"datagroup",
        "form":[
            [ "note", {"label":"Note","type":"textarea","validation":""}]
        ],
```

And the structure of the table is

```
ALTER TABLE `employees` CHANGE `gender` `gender` ENUM('Male','Female')
    CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

If I wish to change Male, female, Married etc into french. 
When I do it I receive truncated error.

Sorry for my english caus I'm french

Comment: javascript and enum?

Comment: Hard to guess without more details on the database and the code that causes the error... As currently asked, this question is *unclear*.

Comment: You should post your database structure and your Java code along with the question.

Comment: And it seems to have nothing to do with Java, my guess is that you mean Javascript instead.

Comment: Please tell me why when I change Male to homme I receive the warning message? what can I do